# Thriller/Horror movie about girl who moves in with couple

Tags: identify-this-movie

Its about a movie a girl who somehow moves in with a couple and is crazy. Has an affair and eventually tries to kill them I think. It is sometime after 2010.

Some descriptions of movie on reddit with no source:

- [Reddit post 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1wfsdi/horror_movie_about_a_crazy_girl_who_moves_into_a/)

> The couple just moved into a new house and let a friend stay with them. The friend starts dating this girl. The girl is like bat-shit crazy. I think she kills the guy? Around the end of the movie she gets in the shower with the husband and they start having sex. He stops it and she goes crazy and tries to kill him. What is the name of this movie?
> EDIT: It is a newer looking movie I saw on Netflix. I'm assuming it wasn't very popular. The cover for it was a attractive brunette girl holding a knife behind her back.

- [Reddit post 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/36jt5e/tomt_movie_girl_moves_in_with_couple_starts_a_bit/)

> I don't remember the exact circumstances, like... why this girl ended up moving in with this couple. I just remember a few "specific" details. Like a scene at night in the couples' swimming pool, don't remember who it involved, just know it happened. I also remember a part where the girl goes into the husbands' work, i think he was a doctor or something, and they start talking in an elevator or something?
> Sorry for being so vague. I watched this movie roughly two years, it was on Netflix at the time, no idea if it still is. I don't know why all of a sudden I'm interested in watching it again, but I am.

**Movies** that are mentioned on the reddits as answer but are **not** the answer:

- Orphan
- Chloe (2009)
- The Hand That Rocks The Cradle
- Ties that bind
- Single White Female
- American Psycho II
- The Roommate

Comment: Maybe "Playing house" (2010)?

Comment: Maybe "Ties That Bind" (2006)?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like ["Thy Neighbor's Wife (2001) aka Poison"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0234890/?ref_=ttmc_mc_tt)

> A scorned woman plots revenge for her husband's suicide by integrating
> herself as a housekeeper for a dysfunctional Beverly Hills family to
> first alienate, and then emotionally and physically destroy them.

Comment: There is a longer review at http://www.efilmcritic.com/review.php?movie=6527 although I don't see any further matching details. Also http://www.beyondhollywood.com/poison-aka-thy-neighbors-wife-2000-movie-review/